# Trouble finding an injection

Tags: group-theory, functions

I am trying to find an injective function that is not invertible (injective but not surjective basically) that maps from $(0,5)$ to $(0,5)$. All of the injective/not surjective functions I can think of are on $\mathbb{R}$ . Any help please?

Thank you.

Comment: $x\mapsto x/2$ does it.

Comment: doesn't it have the inverse $x \mapsto 2x$

Comment: Do not forget that functions have both a domain and a codomain as well as a rule for how to map an input to an output.  The function $f$ with domain $(0,5)$ and codomain $(0,5)$ with the rule $f(x)=\frac{x}{2}$ is indeed injective and not surjective.  For example, there is no preimage to the number $4$, i.e. there is no number $x$ in the range $(0,5)$ such that $f(x)=4$.  The "inverse" you talk about, what I'll call $g(x)=2x$, is not actually a function from $(0,5)$ to $(0,5)$ since for example $g(4)=8$ is not an element of the codomain.

Comment: oh yes! Sorry! I keep visualizing them in $\mathbb{R}$. Thank you very much!